# How can I run PNPM workspace projects as parallel jobs on GitHub Actions?

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, monorepo, pnpm

Given a repository structure with two packages like this:

```
$ tree
.
└── packages
   ├── foo
   └── bar

$ cat pnpm-workspace.yaml
packages:
  - 'packages/**'

$ pnpm -s m ls --depth -1
monorepo /monorepo
@mono/foo@0.0.0 /monorepo/packages/foo
@mono/baz@0.0.0 /monorepo/packages/bar
```

I'd like to run GitHub Actions CI such that it automatically runs each project as separate job. Here I've set up a job that manually does that parallelization:

```
name: CI

on:
  push:

jobs:
  build:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        package: ["@mono/foo", "@mono/bar" ]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: pnpm/action-setup@v2
        with:
          version: 6.9.1
      - run: pnpm run --filter ${{ matrix.package }} test
```

That runs fast because each project is run as parallel jobs, but I don't want to manually maintain that `matrix.package` list. How can I utilize `pnpm` to provide a list of workspace projects that gets fed into GitHub Actions CI?

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm... I hit my head on this a bit more and I've found **a** solution.

I first made a `package.json` script to turn `pnpm` output into a json array-fragment:

```
$ cat package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "list-packages": "echo [$(pnpm -s m ls --depth -1 | tr \" \" \"\n\" | grep -o \"@.*@\" | rev | cut -c 2- | rev | sed -e 's/\\(.*\\)/\"\\1\"/' | paste -sd, - )]",
  }
}
$ pnpm -s list-packages 
["@mono/foo","@mono/bar"]
```

(I'm not good enough with shell to know if there's a much easier way to express this transformation so I'd be happy to learn!)

I then [followed GitHub documentation on dynamically setting matrix variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#example-returning-a-json-object) and created this workflow:

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  packages:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      matrix: ${{ steps.set-matrix.outputs.matrix }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: pnpm/action-setup@v2
        with:
          version: 6.9.1
      - run: $(echo pnpm -s list-packages2)
      - id: set-matrix
        run: echo "::set-output name=matrix::{\"packages\":$(pnpm -s list-packages)}"
  build:
    needs: packages
    strategy:
      matrix: ${{ fromJson(needs.packages.outputs.matrix) }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo ${{ matrix.package }}
```

The `packages` job now takes the output of `$(pnpm -s list-packages)` and puts it into the matrix variable, and that makes GitHub Actions run them all in parallel:

[image: screenshot of GitHub Actions showing a "packages" job that feeds into a Matrix build with two jobs: "mono/foo" and "mono/bar"]